# How to disable italics font in python when defined xlabel or ylabel using subscript

Tags: python, matplotlib, italic

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot()
plt.xlabel(r'Production$_{world}$')
```

[image]

As shown in image red frame, the word 'World' I don't want it to be italicized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding font settings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3),dpi=144)

plt.plot()
plt.xlabel(r'Production$_\mathrm{world}$')
```

[image]